# Vegas Slideshow Plugin - How can I delay the moment the slideshow starts?

Tags: javascript, background, slideshow, delay

I need the initial background image to remain visible for some amount of time before the slideshow begins running. How can I delay the moment the slideshow begins?

I think it should be possible using the setTimeout method, but can't figure out how exactly.

This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$.vegas({
loading:true,
src:'vegas/images/bg1_1.jpg'
});

$.vegas('slideshow', {
delay:6000,
backgrounds:[
{ src:'vegas/images/1_1.jpg', fade:1000,},
{ src:'vegas/images/2_1.jpg', fade:1000,},
{ src:'vegas/images/3_1.jpg', fade:1000,}
]
});
});
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I tried the following, which I'm not sure makes much sense. I know little to nothing of javascript yet.

setTimeout('slideshow',5000);

Comment: That should work -- remove the quotes from the function name and create a function called "slideshow" that starts your slideshow. See [setTimeout examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout). But why not just add `bg1_1.jpg` as the first item in your `backgrounds` array?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply...! The 'slideshow' function already exists in a different file. Would it help if I posted the content of the .js file? Where should I add the setTimeout line of code? I want the first image to load without any fade in effects or anything and then should the slideshow begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout), put your slideshow initialization script inside a function and give that function a name like "startSlideshow":

```
function startSlideshow() {
    // slideshow code goes here
}
```

Then, configure a timeout to call that function after a specified delay:

```
setTimeout(startSlideshow,3000);
```

Example below:

```js
function startSlideshow() {

  // remove pre-slideshow message
  $('p.message').remove();

  // start slideshow
  $.vegas('slideshow', {
    delay: 6000,
    backgrounds: [{
      src: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200',
      fade: 1000,
    }, {
      src: 'http://lorempixel.com/300/200',
      fade: 1000,
    }, {
      src: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/250',
      fade: 1000,
    }]
  });

}

$(function() {
  setTimeout(startSlideshow, 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/js/vegas/jquery.vegas.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/js/vegas/jquery.vegas.js"></script>

<p class="message">Slideshow starts in 3 seconds...</p>
```